# How to add abstract arraylist inside abstract arraylist

Tags: java, class, arraylist, abstract, extends

So I have this problem. I want to make shopping cart program. I declare 3 classes such as Food, Drinks, and Miscs. Those classes become the kind of items that the customer bought. each of the class contain String Name and int price. then there is a Cart class that used to lists the items that the customer bought and also have String Name and int Price.

I want to write at the main class like :

```
public class main{
  public static void main(String[] args){
   Arraylist<Cart> Cart = new Arraylist();
   Foods Food1 = new Foods("Bread", $10);
   Foods Food2 = new Foods("Waffle", $8);
   Drinks Drink1 = new Drinks("Coke", $9);
   Drinks Drink2 = new Drinks("Sprite", $7);
   Miscs Miscs1 = new Miscs("Soap", $5);
   Miscs Miscs2 = new Miscs("Shampoo", $5);

   Cart.add(Food1);
   Cart.add(Food2);
   Cart.add(Drink1);
   Cart.add(Drink2);
   Cart.add(Miscs1);
   Cart.add(Miscs2);
   }}
```

I need to make a method that can add those data type into an arraylist inside cart class. But if I wrote

```
public void add(Arraylist <Cart> cart){
   
}
```

it will only received Cart type data, so I cant input Foods or Drinks, or Miscs type data, even have the same details like name and price.

Answer (score 0):

Use OOP.

Option 1:

Create an abstract class `Item` which has `name` and `price` as property.
`Food`, `Drinks`, and `Miscs` will extends `Item`

`Cart` class has property say `itemList` which would hold list of items.

```
public class Cart {
  List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
  //getter setter
  public void add(Item item) { 
     itemList.add(item);
  }

}
```

Option 2:

Create an `iterface Item` such that `Food`, `Drinks`, and `Miscs` will implement `Item`
`Cart` class stays pretty much same.

Comment: Thanks, I've used implements and also extends. And it looks pretty good. thanks for answering tho